# Why new orange notification Icon without queue?

Tags: discussion, support

I noticed today the new orange notification icon; when I clicked it, it navigated to the suggested edit review queue, but the review queue is empty. Is this normal?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal because that value is cached, and its value is the same for every user. This means the value could be wrong because there aren't anymore posts to review, or the posts to review were flagged / voted to be closed from you.

Comment: Notifications without review queue looks annoying, instead if that notification disappear when there is no queue then its fine! and I love the Idea for review queue notification.

Comment: Can I add feature request tag in my question, if people agree with this.

Comment: @Bala That feature request wouldn't work - the notification is there because of _caching_. So the notification wouldn't be able to disappear any more than it can reflect the exact number of reviews in the queue accurately